# Can a vertical raycast constrain climbing movement correctly if it’s firing in the opposite direction of the character?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, game-physics, raycasting

When my character looks for a ladder to climb, it shoots a ray from the center of its hitbox to a point barely outside the collider. If any part of this ray hits a ladder, it will allow my character to climb up it.

I want to know if there’s a way for me to constrain y movement using a second ray that will only fire once the character is on the ladder, and will fire from the center of the collider to the bottom of the hitbox (essentially mirroring the original ray), but will allow the character to move up until the “tip” of this ray collides with a platform (such as the platform above a ladder). This will halt the y velocity once the character’s feet touch the ground.

I’m having a difficult time understanding how this might work, as I’ve only ever used vertical rays to constrain movement when they are firing in the same direction in which the character is moving. Is this even possible, or will the origin point of this ray just stop the character from moving up to the platform?

Comment: Other than "there won't be anything below the player, otherwise they'd run their head into it first" problem, this seems like a fine solution. Try it, find out, experiment.

Comment: I’m thinking now that it might be better to try to constrain y movement using the first upward raycast by the hit.distance, in addition to the size.y of the collider it hits.

Comment: Mmm, mmm. I see. I see. Try it and find out.